# Simple value input in a Windows program

Tags: c++, dialog

I have a program that runs in the Win32 environment. There is one variable that I would like to set before the program begins. The only reason it is a Win32 program is because I am accessing serial ports. I don't care how I input the variable - it is a number and I suppose a dialog edit box would be best - but I don't know how to go about this with Win32!

Ignoring the bulk of the program, my code is as follows:

```
#include <windows.h>

//Initialise Windows module
int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nFunsterStil)

{
 int variable;

 //ACTION USING THE VARIABLE OCCURS HERE

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access serial port, you don't need windows application. You can create a simple console based application, it will be a still win32 by architecture.

The advantages being using a console application would that you could use 'C' style scanf or C++ style cin to read the input from user.

For the windows application, you need to create a dialog with text box in it and Show the window and wait for user to input, let user to press a 'OK' button or enter.. thats a lot of process..

Just write a console application.. That will do.. Otherwise use MFC..

Comment: Thanks very much. I have simply added <iostream> and used 'cin'. I didn't realise it could be that simple! ^_^ (Will accept answer tomorrow, apparently I'm not allowed to for a few minutes and I gotta dash!)

Comment: "Just use MFC" - very bad advice.

Comment: @Neil, MFC is not bad when you have spend most of your life in raw win32 even WTL..MFC does really neat job IMHO

Comment: I have spent a lot of my life using raw win32. And given the choice between raw win32 and MFC I would probably choose raw Win32. Fortunately, there are many, many options that are better than both of them.

Answer (score 1):

A quick hack:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Initialise Windows module
int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nFunsterStil)

{
 int variable = atoi( lpszArgument );

 //ACTION USING THE VARIABLE OCCURS HERE

 return 0;
}
```

You can then run your program as:

```
myprog.exe 42
```

Creating a dialog via the Windows API is quite complicated. But why are you writing this in C or C++? Why not use C#, or Python?

Comment: I've said pretty much the same thing at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255445/basic-dialog-box-input-for-a-strobe-light-implementation. Why do people double post questions?

Comment: @Andrei I think the OP is a bit confused :-)

Comment: Not having more details about the application, I'd think the OP is familiar with C++ more than C# or Python, or the app has performance requirements that exclude Python and maybe C#, or the OP wants to avoid C# for portability reasons, or the OP is introducing it to a C++ shop, or most of the code is already written in C++, or something like that.  I find the attitude that random programs that happen to run on Windows should use C# or Python odd.

Comment: @David I've been programming on Windows since Windows 2.0, and during all that long, long time I've always tried to use the tools that made life easier for me as a programmer.

Comment: @Neil:  Yes, and one of the possible tools is C++.  There aren't many greenfield Windows-only apps that should use C++, but the shop may be C++, or there may be a desire to avoid C# for increased portability, or it may have performance or other constraints that require C or C++.

Comment: @David You seem to have read my post as an imperative. In fact I asked "Why not use C#, or Python?"